# How do I force a link to a Facebook post to open in-app?

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, url-scheme

I am trying to tweet a link to a 360 video that our company has made. If I copy the link to the post it just opens it up in the browser were the 360 feature is disabled as it only works within the app. Is there a link format or third party service that will force the link to open in-app directly to the post?

Thanks
Connor

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, http://applinks.org/

Comment: AppLinks appears to more about how to setup deeplinks for your own app so that when users go from Facebook to your app that it opens natively. I want to create a link that will open a specific Facebook post in-app.

Comment: Yeah, guess I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of known URL schemes for Facebook. You may be able to find something there, though you would likely still need to wrap it inside a HTTP link redirect before Twitter will able able to handle it: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook